# Finding a weak minimum

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I have been struggling with the following problem I came across in a textbook. I believe that it is necessary to use the Euler-Lagrange Equation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $F$ be the functional defined by
  $$F(u) = \int_0^\pi u'(t)^2 - c u(t)^2\, dt.$$
  Assume that $u(0) = 0 = u(\pi)$.  Find a candidate for the weak minimum of $F$ if we let $c$ be a perfect square.